# How does light absorption work for solids and liquids?

Tags: visible-light, absorption

I've studied in my physics class, absorption and emission spectra for gases or more "spread out" molecules like what is done in atomic absorption spectroscopy (learnt that one in chemistry). As in what discrete wavelengths of light a singular atom absorbs and why it only absorbs those specific wavelengths because of what energy levels its electrons are available to jump to.
I was wondering if this worked generally the same for solids and liquids? Like, when you have something painted black, is the black paint designed to be composed of molecules that absorb enough wavelengths of light to make it look black (it wont be entirely black of course), or is it more that when light hits the surface of the paint, it travels as far as it can through it before using up all its energy to cause electron (and to an extent proton) vibrations? Is it both?
Sorry if this comes off as confusing, I've tried to convey my question(s) as best I can.

Comment: This answer may be helpful: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/547529/313612.

Comment: Thanks, that's pretty much cleared up what I was confused about as a whole.